# Can I summon an unbound Dremora after completing the conjuration ritual quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can the unbound dremora be summoned after the conjuration ritual is complete?
I have the sigil stone and I also completed the quest, but it won't interact with me.  Why is that so?

Comment: that specific dremora or any unbound dremora?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can summon unbound dremora at [Atronach Forge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Atronach_Forge). You need your sigil stone, a daedra heart, a skull and two raw meat. Since a dremora drops daedra heart when they die, you just need one heart, lots of meat and lots of skulls to summon many dremoras. It's a good way to hone your fighting skills and collect enchanted weapons.

Answer (score -1):

You can summon him again if you want, he just won't react to you. He'll fight if you have your followers attack him, and he sometimes fights other daedra. But other than that, he won't react to anything.